# How to put radio buttons in one line inside form?

Tags: css, html, forms, web

I have written the following code:

```
  male    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
female    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">
 other    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="other">
```

All this is inside a form. How can I get them on one single line?

Comment: All else being equal, they will already be on one line.

Comment: if worse comes to worse you could add a CSS style I.E <div type="CSS/TEXT" style="text-align:left"> form </div>

Answer (score 2):

Wrap them in a label tag

```
<label>male    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"></label>
<label>female    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"></label>
<label>other    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="other"></label>
```

also check if no styles are applied to the input elements which may display them as block elements

Comment: Now i see, i put all form in <pre> teg, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dots to go in a line from left to right, you are done. If you want to dots to go from top to bottom you can simple do:

```
  male    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"><br>
female    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"><br>
 other    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="other">
```

`<br>` makes them jump to the next line

Comment: This'll be my next question :) Thanks.

Comment: I put <pre> tag becuse i want output spaces (before male for example) how can i do that don't using <pre>?